# ReactJS errors: "__" is not defined & Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, undefined

How do I resolve these errors in React? I get these upon compiling.

I thought I already had Categories defined, and the other error, I am not sure since I am using a map function - (the goal of that function was to implement accordian.js page into the main app.js page).

App.js code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import Tabs from './Components/Tabs'
import Accordian from './Components/Accordian'

const data = {
  categories: [
    {
      name: 'Faces',
      subCategories: [{ name: 'Yellow', symbols: ['X', 'O', 'P'] }],
    },
    {
      name: 'Flags',
      subCategories: [
        { name: 'Popular', symbols: ['X', 'O', 'P'] },
        { name: 'Unknown', symbols: ['L', 'Z', 'Q'] },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Numbers',
      subCategories: [
        { name: 'Big', symbols: ['X', 'O', 'P'] },
        { name: 'Small', symbols: ['L', 'Z', 'Q'] },
        { name: 'Random', symbols: ['R', 'T', 'M'] },
      ],
    },
  ],
}

const App = () => {
  const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = React.useState(0)
  const handleTabChange = (event, newTabIndex) => {
    setTabIndex(newTabIndex)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">Something</header>
        {categories.map((category) => {
          const { name, subCategories } = category
          return subCategories.map((subCat) => {
            ;<Accordian heading={subCat.name} children={subCat.symbols} />
          })
        })}
        <Typography variant="h3">Placeholder_Symbols</Typography>
        <Tabs
          tab={tabIndex}
          tabs={data.categories}
          handleChange={handleTabChange}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Remove the semicolon before `<Accordian />`:
That one ->`;<Accordian heading={subCat.name} children={subCat.symbols} />`

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in this code.

- When you use map in categories, you forgot put data first.
- You forgot ; when you are using the Accordian component inside maps categories

Test it is the new code and render, I tried and it works:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core/";
import Tabs from "./Components/Tabs";
import Accordian from "./Components/Accordian";

const data = {
  categories: [
    {
      name: "Faces",
      subCategories: [{ name: "Yellow", symbols: ["X", "O", "P"] }]
    },
    {
      name: "Flags",
      subCategories: [
        { name: "Popular", symbols: ["X", "O", "P"] },
        { name: "Unknown", symbols: ["L", "Z", "Q"] }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Numbers",
      subCategories: [
        { name: "Big", symbols: ["X", "O", "P"] },
        { name: "Small", symbols: ["L", "Z", "Q"] },
        { name: "Random", symbols: ["R", "T", "M"] }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const App = () => {
  const [tabIndex, setTabIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const handleTabChange = (event, newTabIndex) => {
    setTabIndex(newTabIndex);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">Something</header>
        {data.categories.map(category => {
          const { name, subCategories } = category;
          return subCategories.map(subCat => (
            <Accordian heading={subCat.name} children={subCat.symbols} />
          ));
        })}
        <Typography variant="h3">Placeholder_Symbols</Typography>
        <Tabs
          tab={tabIndex}
          tabs={data.categories}
          handleChange={handleTabChange}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips! The issue was solved witg the ; but I also forgot to return the other function and define data.categories into it. It's working now ~

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the map function that wasn't returning anything. In this way will return

```js
const data = {
  categories: [
    {
      name: "Faces",
      subCategories: [{ name: "Yellow", symbols: ["X", "O", "P"] }]
    },
    {
      name: "Flags",
      subCategories: [
        { name: "Popular", symbols: ["X", "O", "P"] },
        { name: "Unknown", symbols: ["L", "Z", "Q"] }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Numbers",
      subCategories: [
        { name: "Big", symbols: ["X", "O", "P"] },
        { name: "Small", symbols: ["L", "Z", "Q"] },
        { name: "Random", symbols: ["R", "T", "M"] }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">Something</header>
      {data.categories.map(category => {
        const { name, subCategories } = category;
        return subCategories.map(subCat => (
          <Accordian heading={subCat.name} children={subCat.symbols} />
        ));
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const Accordian = (prop) => {
  return (
    <div>Accordian {prop.heading} - {prop.children}</div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this line of code at the top :
import { useState } from 'react';

Inside const app :
Use useState(0) instead of React.useState(0)

Comment: Its not necessary because he's implementing React and he can use React.useState(0)